# Progress Dialog not showing I have tried all possible solutions but nothing worked

Tags: java, android

Progress Dialog not showing I have tried all possible solutions but nothing worked

This is my **java code** where I am creating an object of *ProgressDialog* and initialized it as well but still, it is not visible on my activity
Am I Starting Service OnCreate as well maybe it affecting my ProgressDialog Is'nt it?

```
    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private ProgressDialog pDialog;
    private ArrayList<CoinDetail> arrayList;
    private FloatingActionButton fab_Coin;
    private ListView coin_details_listView;
    private CoinDetailsAdapter adapter;
    private Toolbar toolbar;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
       pDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
        pDialog.setMessage("Loading...");
        pDialog.setCancelable(false);
      pDialog.show();
    toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        toolbar.setTitleTextColor(Color.WHITE);
        getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Crypto Live");

        Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, ServiceCoin.class);
        startService(i);

        /*mInterstitialAd = newInterstitialAd();    //For ad
        loadInterstitial();*/

        coin_details_listView = findViewById(R.id.lv_coinName_mainActivity);
        fab_Coin = findViewById(R.id.fab_add_coin);

        arrayList = new ArrayList<>();
        adapter = new CoinDetailsAdapter(MainActivity.this, arrayList);
        coin_details_listView.setAdapter(adapter);
        CoinSingleton.getInstance().setContext(this);
        adapter = CoinSingleton.getInstance().getCoinDetailsAdapter(pDialog);
        coin_details_listView.setAdapter(adapter);
       coin_details_listView.setTextFilterEnabled(true);
        fab_Coin.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, FabCoins.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });

        coin_details_listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

                Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, CoinDetails.class);
                intent.putExtra("SHORT", CoinSingleton.getInstance().getCoinDetails().get(position).getShort());
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });

    }
    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();

        inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu2, menu);
        // Retrieve the SearchView and plug it into SearchManager
         SearchView searchView = (SearchView) MenuItemCompat.getActionView(menu.findItem(R.id.action_search));
        SearchManager searchManager = (SearchManager) getSystemService(SEARCH_SERVICE);
        searchView.setSearchableInfo(searchManager.getSearchableInfo(getComponentName()));
 searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {


        if (TextUtils.isEmpty(newText)) {
            coin_details_listView.clearTextFilter();
        } else {
            coin_details_listView.setFilterText(newText);
        }
        return true;
    }
});
        return true;
    }
}
```

CoinSingleton java class

```
public class CoinSingleton {

    private Context context;
    private static CoinSingleton singleton = null;
    private ArrayList<CoinDetail> coinDetails = new ArrayList<>();
    private CoinDetailsAdapter coinDetailsAdapter;

    public void setCoinDetails(ArrayList<CoinDetail> coinDetails) {
        this.coinDetails = coinDetails;
    }

    /* A private Constructor prevents any other
     * class from instantiating.
     */
    private CoinSingleton() {
    }

    /* Static 'instance' method */
    public static CoinSingleton getInstance() {
        if (singleton == null) {
            singleton = new CoinSingleton();
        }
        return singleton;
    }

    public void setContext(Context context) {
        this.context = context;
    }

    public void setCoinDetailsAdapter(ArrayList<CoinDetail> details) {
        for (int i = 0; i < details.size(); i++) {
            try {
                coinDetails.get(i).setPrice(details.get(i).getPrice());
                coinDetails.get(i).setMktcap(details.get(i).getMktcap());
            } catch (Exception e) {
                coinDetails.add(details.get(i));
            }
        }
        coinDetailsAdapter.setCoinDetailsArrayList(coinDetails);
        //Toast.makeText(context, "Adapter set"+details.get(0).getPrice()+details.get(0).getShort(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        coinDetailsAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    public CoinDetailsAdapter getCoinDetailsAdapter(ProgressDialog dialog) {
        coinDetailsAdapter = new CoinDetailsAdapter(context, coinDetails);
dialog.dismiss();
        return coinDetailsAdapter;
    }

    public ArrayList<CoinDetail> getCoinDetails() {
        return coinDetails;
    }
}
```

Comment: What if you move `pDialog.show();` into `onResume()` rather than `onCreate();`? I have a feeling you're showing the dialog too early in the activity lifecycle.

Comment: Not worked problem still exists

Comment: Your dialog code is working. I think here `CoinSingleton.getInstance().getCoinDetailsAdapter(pDialog);` is dismissing your `pDialog`. Try to comment below part.

Comment: upload `CoinSingleton.java`

Comment: Removing it makes my dialog visible forever I have edited my code see and now tell what is the issue

Answer (score 0):

I think you are missing progressDialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_SPINNER);

```
  ProgessDialog progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(ctx);
        progressDialog.setMessage("Updating...");
        progressDialog.setIndeterminate(true);
        progressDialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_SPINNER);
        progressDialog.setCancelable(false);
```

Edit

```
new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()).postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                pDialog = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
                pDialog.setMessage("Loading...");
                pDialog.setCancelable(false);
                pDialog.show();
            }
        },100);
```

Comment: Please check edit answer , I think your service block the dialog.

Comment: My App crashed now

Comment: Let me check . this issue is happened due to service.

Comment: Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.app.ProgressDialog.dismiss()' on a null object reference

Comment: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13347253/show-progressdialog-in-a-service-class/13347389#13347389) check this link.
and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38974627/adding-android-progress-dialog-inside-background-service-with-asynctask-getting/39064895)

Comment: I am not using Async Task in my service so it will not help  my question

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you're passing `pDialog` and dismissing. `dialog.dismiss()` removes your dialog.

```
public CoinDetailsAdapter getCoinDetailsAdapter(ProgressDialog dialog) {
    coinDetailsAdapter = new CoinDetailsAdapter(context, coinDetails);
    dialog.dismiss();
    return coinDetailsAdapter;
}
```

if you want to dismiss dialog with delay try this code. Your dialog will be dismissed after 3 seconds.

```
public CoinDetailsAdapter getCoinDetailsAdapter(final ProgressDialog dialog) {
    coinDetailsAdapter = new CoinDetailsAdapter(context, coinDetails);

    new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()).postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            pDialog.dismiss();
        }
    }, 3000);
    return coinDetailsAdapter;
}
```

Comment: So,what is the matter I need to dismiss my dialog as soon as my adapter is filled

Comment: @Xay your adapter is filled very fast and you're not able to see the dialog.